# Custom Python string codec with different-length characters?

Tags: python, character-encoding

Is it possible to make a custom Python [codec](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html) with pure-python code where a character of that codec can be more than one regular `str` or `unicode` character, like the way that in the "unicode" encoding in Python 2.x, two ASCII characters can be one unicode character? (So, for example, `'.' in '%.'` would be false if '.' and '%.' were each 1 character)

If this is possible, is there a way to get that codec to work properly with all the string methods? (So, for example...

```
a = 'qwerty.uio%.p'.encode('aencoding')
a.split('.'.encode('aencoding'))
```

...would return a tuple containing `qwerty` and `uio%.p`)

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly come up with a custom encoding which uses more than one byte to represent a single character. One example of this is UTF-8.

The Python `str` type stores bytes and has no knowledge of the encoding scheme used to produce those bytes. For example, UTF-8 uses 2 bytes to represent the unicode character `'\u00f1'`:

```
>>> s1 = u'\u00f1'.encode('utf-8')
>>> s1
'\xc3\xb1'
```

And the `str` operations have no knowledge that the bytes `'\xc3\xb1'` represents a single character:

```
>>> '\xc3' in s1
True
>>> s1.__contains__('\xc3')
True
```

Some questions you might consider when designing your encoding:  How many distinct symbols do you need to encode? Do you have more escape characters than just `'%'`? Are you only dealing with 1- and 2-byte sequences?

Without knowing more about your encoding I can give you an example of how it might be done. You could transform your `str` representation to `unicode` and use its efficient methods to compare, split, and concatenate your values:

```
>>> s1 = '.'.decode('aencoding')
>>> s1
u'\u002e'
>>> s2 = 'x.y%.z'.decode('aencoding')
>>> s2
u'\u0078\u002e\u0079\u252e\u007a'
>>> s2.split(s1)
[u'x', u'y\u252ez'
>>> u'y\u252ez'.encode('aencoding')
'y%.z'
```

Comment: You can also have an encoding which uses one byte to represent multiple characters.